# removing extra xml declaration from the soap payload

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, version

A product vendor is calling my web service with a soap message which is incorrect in terms of syntax. The reason being the soap message has a redundant xml declaration before the payload that carries sales data. This interface is supposed to transfer over 500K transactions/day. What are my options in ripping off the second xml declaration without compromising performance significantly?
I can't apply something like below since in this case xml declaration is not at the beginning. Besides the xml syntax is incorrect.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

Soap message

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:postTransaction xmlns:ns2="http://v1.ws.abc.dtv/">
<rawLogString>
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--unwanted xml declaration-->
   <Log><!--elements that carry sale data-->
   </Log>
</rawLogString>
</ns2:postTransaction>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standards-compliant XML or XSL tool will process your sample SOAP message, as it is malformed: there can only be one XML declaration in the file, and if there is a declaration, it must be the very first thing in the file -- not even whitespace can come before it.

I infer from this that your SOAP message is not being emitted by a compliant XML or XSL tool.

My advice at this point would be to do one of two things:

1. Contact the vendor and explain that their tool is emitting invalid XML, and that this must be fixed.
2. Implement your own process to strip the unwanted XML declaration.  When doing so, you **cannot** use XSL to process the whole message -- you're better off using a text-based search-and-replace tool.  For example, you could use the following regular expression to find the offending declaration, and replacing it with `$1` will remove it, while maintaining other content:

   ```
   (>\s+)<\?xml [^>]+>
   ```

Comment: Pretty much what I thought but just wanted to confirm before I pick a fight with the big guys!